# SQL show difference between 2 tables

Tags: sql

I know there are similar questions, but I can't find solution to what I need to do.

First of all I have 2 tables :

- SD.Airlines (16k+ rows)
- SD.AirlineRatings (405 rows)

I need to find which records form SD.AirlineRatings do I have in SD.Airlines, I did this :

```
SELECT b.Name AS Airline FROM SD.Airlines b
LEFT JOIN SD.AirlineRatings a ON a.AirlineName = b.Name
WHERE a.AirlineName IS NOT NULL;
```

Works fine, showed me 249/405 records. Now... If I need to compare those 249 records towards SD.AirlineRatings and check which ones I don't have.

I bet answer is simple but I don't know SQL that much.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want records in `AirLines` ratings that are also in `Airlines`, then I would recommend `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
select a.*
from sd.Airlines a
where exists (select 1 from sd.AirlineRatings ar where ar.AirlineName = a.Name);
```

If you want unrated airlines:

```
select a.*
from sd.Airlines a
where not exists (select 1 from sd.AirlineRatings ar where ar.AirlineName = a.Name);
```

And, if you want ratings on airlines that don't exist, you would swap the two tables in the query.